# Why are the bootstrap and CDF estimates of the 60% quantile significantly different?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

```
Remove["Global`*"]
data = N[{1.67655096`, 1.73234376`, 1.8965016000000001`, 2.06723664`, 
2.19692088`, 2.20885056`, 2.21420304`, 2.2199184`, 2.25389304`, 
2.2695422400000003`, 2.42848368`, 2.62902024`, 2.65727952`, 
2.76596208`, 2.95570296`, 3.15574056`, 3.25290168`, 
3.5498735999999997`, 3.8103760799999997`, 3.88707984`, 
4.00737456`, 4.1241312`, 4.34081592`, 4.56303456`, 4.57950024`}];
(*Define distribution*)
dist = LogNormalDistribution[\[Mu], \[Sigma]];
(*Find distribution parameters*)
FindDistributionParameters[data, dist]
(*Bootstrap*)
sample = RandomVariate[
dist /. {\[Mu] -> 1.030902937776725`, \[Sigma] -> 
  0.30525966657758447`}, 1000000];
Bootstrapping := {\[Mu], \[Sigma]} /. 
FindDistributionParameters[RandomChoice[sample, Length@data], dist];
BootEstimates = ParallelTable[Bootstrapping, {10000}];
(*Bootstrap Standard Deviation estimation*)
BootStd = 
StandardDeviation /@ Transpose[BootEstimates]
(*Bootstrap: There is a 60% probability that the true value of \[Mu] \
is below 1.0473.*)
{Quantile[#, 0.6]} & /@ Transpose[BootEstimates]

(*CDF calculation: There is a 60% probability that the true value of \
\[Mu] is below 3.029.*)
Solve[
CDF[LogNormalDistribution[1.030902937776725`, 0.30525966657758447`], 
x] == 0.6]
```

Comment: Are those parameters you plug into a `LogNormalDistribution` in the beginning supposed to be the exact same as those you plug into a `NormalDistribution` at the end?

Comment: They should both be LogNormalDistribution; I fixed that.

Comment: From the last line I get `3.029021378646146`. Maybe you need an extra step: `Mean[LogNormalDistribution[μ, 0.3052596665775844]] == 3.029021378646146 // Solve` ?

Comment: I think you are mixing up two different concepts.  The bootstrap process (which you perform in a very nonstandard way - and I'll comment on that next) gets one an idea about the sampling distribution of the estimator of $\mu$ (and $\sigma$ for that matter).  The last piece of code (`Solve[...==0.6]`) gets you the value of a single observation for which 60% of randomly selected values are less than that value.

Comment: I look forward to your comment!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is first an extended comment followed by an answer to the question.

**Extended comment**

Typically one chooses the usual nonparametric bootstrap by resampling from the observed data (labeled "Simple bootstrap` below) or from a known functional form of a distribution but with the parameter estimates used in place of the unknown parameters:

```
(* Simple bootstrap *)
simpleBootstrap := {μ, σ} /. 
   FindDistributionParameters[RandomChoice[data, Length@data], dist];
simpleBS = ParallelTable[simpleBootstrap, {10000}];
simpleBSseμ = StandardDeviation[simpleBS[[All, 1]]]
simpleBSseσ = StandardDeviation[simpleBS[[All, 2]]]

(* Parametric bootstrap *)
mle = FindDistributionParameters[data, dist]
parametricBootstrap := {μ, σ} /. 
   FindDistributionParameters[RandomVariate[dist /. mle, Length@data],
     dist];
parametricBS = ParallelTable[parametricBootstrap, {10000}];
parametricBSseμ = StandardDeviation[parametricBS[[All, 1]]]
parametricBSseσ = StandardDeviation[parametricBS[[All, 2]]]
```

Your method seems to be a parametric bootstrap but with an extra step of generating 1,000,000 samples from the estimated distribution.  While the results will likely be nearly identical, that extra step is unnecessary.

**Answer**

The bootstrap is giving you the estimate of the value where 60% of the sampling distribution of the estimate of $\mu$ is below.

The `Solve[...==0.6]` part of your code which can be written as

```
InverseCDF[LogNormalDistribution[1.030902937776725`, 0.30525966657758447`], 0.6]
```

is giving you the estimated value for which a single random sample will be below 60% of the time.

So the two values are not comparable and certainly shouldn't be the same.

Comment: Thanks! Can you please recommend a reference for learning more about this stuff?

Comment: Also, are there any built-in MMA functions which will calculate/estimate the standard errors of the estimators obtained from FindDistributionParameters?

Comment: The Wikipedia page on the bootstrap is a place to start.  One of the references listed is https://statistics.stanford.edu/sites/default/files/BIO%2083.pdf.  As far as built-in MMA functions, I don't think there are any.  One needs to use the `LogLikelihood` function you referenced in another question.